# Как десериализовать кривой json в котором ключи это значения?

Tags: android, gson

Есть json

```
{
  "message":{
      "affenpinscher":[],
      "african":[],
      "bulldog":["boston","french"],
      ...
      "retriever":["chesapeake","curly","flatcoated","golden"]
      ...
      "wolfhound":["irish"]
    }
}
```

https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all

Я пытаюсь десериализовать это в следующую структуру  >> Вот мой десериализатор:

```
public class BreedDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Map<String, List<String>>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, List<String>> dogBreeds = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("message"), type);



           return dogBreeds;
        }
    }
```

Перед вызовом метода deserialize json-строку я проверял, там именно объект "message" c масссивом значений. Но в итоге метод возвращает null.

Answer (score 0):

По спецификациям json этот абсолютно валидный.
Пробуйте так:

```
public class MessagesResponse {

    private String status;
    private Map<List<String>> message;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

---

```
MessagesResponse response = gson.fromJson(json, MessagesResponse.class);
Map<List<String>> message = response.getMessages();
```